# Am getting an error on my php code to send sms

Tags: php, mysql, kannel

Am a newbie and i am getting an error on line 26 of my code i cant understand what causes the error as it is making me not to be able to send sms anyhelp will be appreciated

```
        <?php
        $gw_host="10.0.0.9";
     $value=$_POST['value'];
     urlencode($message)=$_POST['message'];
     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","db_host","xxxxxx");

         if (!$con)
         {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         }

         mysql_select_db("aic_sms", $con);

     $result = mysql_query("SELECT phn_number FROM users WHERE message=$value");
     if($result){
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         function sendSmsMessage($phn_number, $message)
        {
            $ch= curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, "http://10.0.0.15/process_sms/sendsms.php?recipient=$phn_number&msg=" . urlencode($message));
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

           }
       }
    else {
       echo mysql_error();
   }
   }

   echo 'Message sent successfully';    



      mysql_close($con);
      ?>
```

Comment: With sql injection you could get the script to message everyone in the database. :s also your iterating a function, that would cause the function tobe defined twice, resulting in the error.

Comment: try this `$result = mysql_query("SELECT phn_number FROM users WHERE message=".$value);` instead of this `$result = mysql_query("SELECT phn_number FROM users WHERE message=$value");`

Comment: or maybe you're supposed to write your SQL-select like this `$result = mysql_query("SELECT phn_number FROM users WHERE message='".$value."'");`

Comment: Or maybe, the function definition within the `while` loop isn't exactly right.

Comment: pretty hard to know which row is number 26 :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first off you have a function within a loop this will cause the function tobe defined twice then kill your script, with functions you define them once then use the function name to execute the code within the function, also the actual curl function you are using wont work as your not setting the correct options.

Plus you should use prepared query's to execute SQL statements, as in your current script you are vulnerable to sql injection, someone malicious could post `someval OR 1=1` this would cause mysql to return everything as 1=1 which is true.

Heres how you should perhaps do it and build appon it. Hope it helps

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){

    $value  = $_POST['value'];
    $message= $_POST['message'];

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=aic_sms", 'username', 'password');

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT phn_number FROM users WHERE message=:message");

        /*** bind the paramaters ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(':message', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
        $stmt->execute();

        /*** fetch the results ***/
        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            $result[$row['phn_number']] = sendSmsMessage($row['phn_number'], $message);
        }
        //perhaps do somthing with the $result array
        echo 'Messages sent successfully';   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}else{
    //Show form or whatever
}


function sendSmsMessage($phn_number, $message){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://10.0.0.15/process_sms/sendsms.php?recipient=$phn_number&msg=" . urlencode($message));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $html;
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much let me try that and build upon it i will let you know if i get stuck. again thank you once more